# TensorFlow saver.save() not working consistently - results in core dump and "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' "

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, jupyter-lab, coredump

I'm training a model using Tensorflow that requires massively memory-intensive input data, so I'm using a for loop to recursively load in new training data. At the end of each loop I save the model with a `model.save()` method in the following way:

```
 def save(self, sess=None):
    if not sess:
        raise AttributeError("TensorFlow session not provided.")
    saver = tf.train.Saver(self.vars)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./tmp/%s.ckpt" % self.name)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

I then reload the model in the next iteration of the loop by instantiating a model object and then calling `model.load()`, which looks like this:

```
    def load(self, sess=None):
        if not sess:
             raise AttributeError("TensorFlow session not provided.")
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./tmp/%s.ckpt.meta' % self.name)
        save_path = "./tmp/%s.ckpt" % self.name
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tmp/'))
        print("Model restored from file: %s" % save_path)
```

Normally, the model will save and load without any issues as I loop through the training datasets.

However, on some iterations of the loop, I get the following error when saving the model:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::append
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Thread 0x00007fd3a5080700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd55f4ed700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner  File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd499374700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd57cf17700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd14affd700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd14b7fe700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164 in get
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/writer/event_file_writer.py", line 159 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fd62af20700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 299 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 551 in wait
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_monitor.py", line 69 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007fd63926c700 (most recent call first):
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3166 in _as_graph_def
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3238 in as_graph_def
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1246 in export_meta_graph
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1203 in save
File "/home/dxcl/graph_model/models.py", line 85 in save
File "/home/dxcl/graph_model/unsupervised_train.py", line 351 in train
File "/home/dxcl/graph_model/unsupervised_train.py", line 362 in main
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250 in _run_main
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299 in run
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40 in run
File "/home/dxcl/graph_model/unsupervised_train.py", line 365 in <module>
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
File "/home/dxcl/conda_envs/py_env_2/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193 in _run_module_as_main
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've noticed this doesn't happen when I reduce the amount of training data fed in each loop, so it could be a memory-related issue. I just don't understand why it would work on some occasions but not others though?

(I'm running tensorflow-gpu 1.15, and doing so in a JupyterLab terminal. Happy to supply any other relevant details or code!)